# Why difference in out when using Jmeter to load test vs HP Load runner?

Tags: jmeter, stress-testing

Here is the scenario

We are load testing a web application. The application is deployed on two VM servers with a a hardware load balancer distributing the load.

There are tow tools used here 
1. HP Load Runner (an expensive tool).
2. JMeter - free

JMeter was used by development team to test for a huge number of users. It also does not have any licensing limit like Load Runner.

How the tests are run ?
A URL is invoked with some parameters and web application reads the parameter , process results and generates a pdf file.

When running the test we found that for a load of 1000 users spread over period of 60 seconds, our application took 4 minutes to generate 1000 files.
Now when we pass the same url through JMeter, 1000 users with a ramp up time of 60 seconds,
application takes 1 minutes and 15 seconds to generate 1000 files.

I am baffled here as to why this huge difference in performance.

Load runner has rstat daemon installed on both servers.

Any clues ?

Comment: Did you get an answer for your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really have four possibilities here:

1. You are measuring two different things.   Check your timing record structure.
2. Your request and response information is different between the two tools.  Check with Fiddler or Wireshark.
3. Your test environment initial conditions are different yielding different results.  Test 101 stuff, but quite often overlooked in tracking down issues like this.
4. You have an overloaded load generator in your loadrunner environment which is causing all virtual users to slow.  For example you may be logging everything resulting in your file system becoming a bottleneck for the test.   Deliberately underload your generators, reduce your logging levels and watch how you are using memory for correlations so you don't create a physical memory oversubscribed condition which results in high swap activity.

As to the comment above as to JMETER being faster, I have benchmarked both and for very complex code the C based solution for Loadrunner is faster upon execution from iteration to iteration than the Java based solution in JMETER.  (method:  complex algorithm for creating data files on the fly for upload for batch mortgage processing. p3: 800Mhz. 2GB of RAM.  LoadRunner 1.8 million iterations per hour ungoverned for a single user.  JMETER, 1.2 million)   Once you add in pacing it is the response time of the server which is determinate to both.

It should be noted that LoadRunner tracks its internal API time to directly address accusations of the tool influencing the test results.   If you open the results set database set (.mdb or Microsoft SQL server instance as appropriate) and take a look at the [event meter] table you will find a reference for "Wasted Time."   The definition for wasted time can be found in the LoadRunner documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the culprit is in HOW the scripts are structured.

Things to consider:

- Think / wait time: When recording,
  Jmeter does not automatically put in
  waits.
- Items being requested: Is
  Jmeter ONLY requesting/downloading
  HTML pages while Load runner gets all
  embedded files?
- Invalid Responses:
  are all 1000 Jmeter responses valid? 
  If you have 1000 threads from a
  single desktop, I would suspect you
  killed Jmeter and not all your
  responses were valid.

Comment: All the JMeter responses are valid. I check the count of files. Another interesting thing to note is that this call to server is asynchronous request. You do not have to wait for response to come back.

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget that the testing application itself measures itself, since the arrival of the response is based on the testing machine time. So from this perspective it could be the answer, that JMeter is simply faster.

The second thing to mention is the wait times mentioned by BlackGaff.

Always check results with result tree in jmeter.

And always put the testing application onto separate hardware to see real results, since testing application itself loads the server.